# Ajuda com COMBOBOX, Selecionar cidades de acordo com estado escolhido

Tags: php, html, combobox, html-select, html-option

Estou programando uma aplicação em php e tenho todos os estados e cidades do Brasil no banco Mysql.

> Na tabela Estados tenho: `id`, `nome`, `uf`.
>
> Na tabela Cidades tenho: `id`, `nome`, `id_estado`.

Criei um select para os estados e gostaria que quando clicasse no option de um determinado estado, aparecesse as cidades desse estado no select das cidades.

Abaixo o codigo

```
<?php include_once "conexao.php"; ?>
<html>
    Estado:
    <select name="estado" id="estado">
    <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT `id`,`nome`, `uf` FROM estado WHERE `pais` = 1 ORDER BY `nome`";
        $res = $mysqli->query($sql);
        while($r = $res->fetch_array()) {
           $r = array_map('utf8_encode', $r);
           $sigla = $r["uf"];
           $nome = $r["nome"];
           $id = $r["id"];

           echo "<option value='$id'> $nome </option>";          
        }
        
     ?>     

    </select>
  Cidade:
    <select name="cidade" id="cidade">
        <option value="">Cidade</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Coloque os códigos que você já fez até agora

Comment: Amigo coloque os códigos para ficar mais fácil para te ajudar!

Comment: @Phelipe fiz até aí...

Comment: @hugocsl como o value no primeiro select corresponde ao id de cada estado, o que eu pensei em fazer era capturar o value do option selecionado, e colocar no where do sql que listaria as cidades no outro select. Porém não tenho a menor ideia de como fazer isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa *popular* de forma dinâmica o `select` das cidades. Para isso você pode usar Ajax com JavaScript puro ou jQuery.

Funciona da seguinte forma: ao selecionar um Estado, o script irá enviar para uma página PHP o código do Estado, e essa página irá fazer a requisição ao banco de dados de todas as cidades com o código do Estado recebido, em seguida retornar um HTML com as `options` que será inserida no `select` das cidades.

Vou dar um exemplo básico usando jQuery, que fica mais fácil, e você pode aplicar no seu código com tranquilidade:

Capturar o `value` do `select` dos Estados quando for selecionado e chamar o Ajax:

```
$("#estado").on("change", function(){
    var id_estado = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'cidades.php',
        data: { estado: id_estado }
        dataType: 'html',
        complete: function(result) {
            $("#cidade").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

No Ajax acima, eu envio o `id` do Estado selecionado para uma página PHP chamada `cidades.php` (você pode usar o nome que quiser). Esta página `cidades.php` vai ficar responsável de retornar a lista de cidades do Estado selecionado. Essa página não deve conter outra coisa senão os códigos PHP e a construção das `options` que será inserida no `select` das cidades. Não é uma página comum, com `<html><head><body>` etc...

**Página `cidades.php`:**

Como dito, a única utilidade desta página é retornar as `options` para o `select` cidades.

O esquema desta página seria:

```
<?php
$estado = $_GET['estado']; // recebendo o id do Estado enviado pelo Ajax

if(isset($estado) && !empty($estado)){

    // FAZER A REQUISIÇÃO AO BANCO DE DADOS USANDO A VARIÁVEL
    // $estado PARA PEGAR APENAS AS CIDADES COM ESSE id

    // AQUI FAZER UM LOOP NOS RESULTADOS
    while(ENQUANTO HOUVER RESULTADO VINDO DO BANCO){

        echo "<option value='$ID_DA_CIDADE'>$NOME_DA_CIDADE</option>";

    }

}
?>
```

Para chamar as cidades no carregamento da página, pois o primeiro Estado no `select` já vem selecionado, você pode usar o jQuery abaixo, que dispara um *trigger* no `select`:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
    $("#estado").trigger("change");
});
```

Não esqueça de carregar o jQuery na sua `<head>`. Você pode usar este:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Então, o script jQuery completo ficaria:

```
<script>
$("#estado").on("change", function(){
    var id_estado = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'cidades.php',
        data: { estado: id_estado }
        dataType: 'html',
        complete: function(result) {
            $("#cidade").append(result);
        }
    });
});

$(window).on("load", function(){
    $("#estado").trigger("change");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Amigo, na minha máquina o ajax não está enviando o ID do estado pra página que retorna as cidades... Testei o mesmo código na máquina de um amigo e funcionou perfeitamente.. Tem ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: O Ajax soh funciona em servidor. Se tentar na maquina local nao dah certo.

Comment: @MichaelCampos Seria isso?

Answer (score 0):

O mais aconselhável é fazer uma requisição ajax para uma página que retorna um JSON com os valores de id e o nome de cada cidade referente ao ID que enviamos. Caso use Jquery o código vai ser algo como:

```
$('#estado').change(function(){
    $('.sair').remove();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        data: {id: $('#estado').val()},
        url: 'listar-cidades.php',
        success: function(retorno){
            for(i = 0; i < retorno.length; i++) {
                $('#cidade').append('<option class="sair" value="'+retorno[i].id+'" >'+retorno[i].nome+'</option>')
            }
        }
    });
});
```

O que estamos fazendo nesse código JS é sempre que o campo com ID mudar seu estado ele vai mandar uma requisição ajax para a página `listar-cidades.php` com o `id` que o usuário selecionou. Esse código espera um JSON formatado da seguinte forma:

```
[{"id":"1","nome":"Brasília"},{"id":"2","nome":"Taguatinga"},{...}]
```

Agora basta construir o script php que retorna esses dados recuperando o `id` que enviamos.

Comment: Estou começando a programar agora, meus conhecimentos estão limitados a html, css e PHP... Esse tipo de dica ajuda bastante a ampliar meu campo de visão! Obrigado!!

Comment: Dê uma pesquisada então em Javascript e em requisições ajax. São tecnologias essenciais no desenvolvimento web. O Jquary nada mais é que um  framework javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Já é antigo este post mas vou por uma solução simples somente com PHP que esta útil pra mim.
Não sei se teria como aplicar no código pra funcionar aqui mas enfim.
No banco tem estados e cidades.
No perfil do usuário tem estado e cidade salvo.
Aparece para edição na sua página. Ele querendo trocar de estado, inseri um onchange que seta o select como selecionado e exibe no select cidades as cidades do estado selecionado. Se ele salvar, update no banco, caso contrário nada mudará ao atualizar a página.
Tosco, simples mas funciona sem outra linguagem. Na minha cabeça, de java, só entra o alert rsrsrsr

```html
<?php 
/*****************************************/

if (isset($_POST['estado'])) {
    $estadoSelect = $_POST['estado'];
}else{
    $estadoSelect = $uf; // este $uf é o que esta salvo do usuário numa session ou variável qualquer em algum lugar
}
/*****************************************/
?>

        <label class="form-label">ESTADO</label>
        <select class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="estado">
            <?php 
                $select = SELECT("*", "estados", "");
                foreach ($select as $dados) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $dados['estados_uf']; ?>" <?php if($estadoSelect == $dados['estados_uf']){ echo "selected"; } ?>><?php echo $dados['estados_nome']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
        </select>  


        <label class="form-label">CIDADE</label>
        <select class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="cidades">
            <?php 
                $select = SELECT("*", "cidades", " WHERE cidade_uf = '$estadoSelect'");
                foreach ($select as $dados) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $dados['cidade_nome']; ?>" <?php if($cidade == $dados['cidade_nome']){ echo "selected"; } ?>><?php echo $dados['cidade_nome']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).